# ScrollView and removing borders

Tags: ios, xcode, scrollview

I have created a scrollview as per the following instructions:
[ScrollView tutorial](https://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwignO_G0JTVAhWHd5oKHengBXgQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.raywenderlich.com%2F159481%2Fuiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started&usg=AFQjCNEwSCfMnxeGLvjZfd9Ek5LreRU0mg)
. The storyboard hierarchy looks the following:

[image]

During the creation, i have created auto-layout constraints on both the ScrollView and the embedded UIImageview.

However, the colour of the upper View is still visible as below, in green:
[image]

However I would like to have a full view for the image view without those green colours from upper view. Following options have been tried:

- Setting the scroll view frame with the upper view frame as:

  self.scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
- Disable the auto adjust inset option as:

  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
- Having the scrollview insets to 0 :

  self.scrollView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

None of the above options work. Intriguing thing it is possible to see those green colour of the upper view not only in runtime but also in the storyboard (screenshot above is from the storyboard). Note also that both the ScrollView and UIImageview are in 0,0 position and also match the exact height and width of the above frame.

Would you know what option  to avoid those green colours from the upper view to be visible?

Comment: Create a chat room or ping me on skype psspl.ios.dev2@outlook.com.its a constraint issue

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + drag scrollview to its superview and give **HORIZONTAL CENTER** constraint.[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It does not work unfortunately in this scenario. The green border of the superview remains.

Comment: first remove all programmatically given constraint or comment it.

Answer (score 0):

- set your viewcontroller hierarchy as image shown.

[image]

- give scrollview 4 constraint. show in image below.

[image]

- than give 4 constraint to view inside superview. from image below.

[image]

- also give equal width and equal height constraint to view respect to
  scrollview. similar to image below.

[image]

- lastly select image inside view and give four constraint to it. as
  image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive help. I am meeting one challenge , the content view becomes sized to the size of the superview and therefore it becomes a view which can no longer scrolled, as soon as i implement the constraints on equal width.

Comment: I have managed to find a way which consist of putting the constraints from content view to scrollview with a -10 on all four constraint values instead of 0. In such way it hides the borders. It may not be the cleanest but it works... Of course i am open to hear out the other alternative...

Comment: dont give -10 value, if your content view is not scrolling increase its height to 800 and doing that your content view bottom constraint will set its value in minus(-), set its value to 0 and update your constraint.